# Trying to Find the Slope Fit of A Log Log Plot

Tags: plotting, data

I need to find the linear slope on a log log plot for small values x and for large values of x, but I am not sure how. You can only fit data right, so how do I tell it to fit a log log plot? Here is my graph and my data:

```
 MuhData={{0.7366, 0.238124}, {1.016, 0.844452}, {1.4732, 2.30787}, {1.938, 
  4.91981}, {0.3048, 0.00808025}, {0.5131, 0.0588889}};
loglogstuff = 
 ListLogLogPlot[{MuhData}, 
   PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
   PlotMarkers -> {{\[FilledSquare], 15}}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    PointLegend[Automatic, {"Large"}, 
     LegendFunction -> Frame]]
```

If I get a linear fit for small values it tells me the power relationship and same for large values. Somehow I need to find 1 fit for each (small values and large values of x) and it needs to be linear. Any help on how to do this is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LogLogPlot` just takes the `Log` of the data and provides some neat formatting of the axes:

```
GraphicsRow[{ListLogLogPlot[MuhData, Frame -> True], 
  ListPlot[Log[MuhData], Frame -> True]}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

So you can just fit a line to the `Log` of the data:

```
lm = LinearModelFit[Log[MuhData], x, x];
Normal[lm]
```

> -0.498215 + 3.49921 x

```
Show[Plot[Normal@lm, {x, -1.5, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True], loglogstuff]
```

[image]

Or (like in [BlacKow's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128560/22013)):

```
f0 = Normal[lm] /. x -> Log[x] // Exp
```

> 0.607614 x^3.49921

```
Show[LogLogPlot[f0, {x, 0.2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True], loglogstuff]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

To fit separately for small and large `x` values I'd `Take`, according to the [comment of OP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128554/trying-to-find-the-slope-fit-of-a-log-log-plot/128558?noredirect=1#comment347752_128558), the first two and last two points and do separate fits:

```
lm1 = LinearModelFit[Take[Log@MuhData, 2], x, x]
Normal[lm1]
```

> -0.231552 + 3.93645 x

```
lm2 = LinearModelFit[Take[Log@MuhData, -2], x, x]
Normal[lm2]
```

> -0.287282 + 3.8137 x

```
Show[Plot[Normal@lm1, {x, -1.5, 0}, PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True], 
 Plot[Normal@lm2, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  Frame -> True], loglogstuff, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Or

```
f1 = Normal[lm1] /. x -> Log[x] // Exp
f2 = Normal[lm2] /. x -> Log[x] // Exp

Show[LogLogPlot[f1, {x, 0.3, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True], 
 LogLogPlot[f2, {x, 1, 2}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  Frame -> True], loglogstuff, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

---

A bit more general: if one defines "small `x`" such that `x<1`, and "large" as `x>1`, then one can `Select` the data for respective fits:

```
lm3 = LinearModelFit[Log@Select[MuhData, #[[1]] < 1 &], x, x]
Normal[lm3]
```

> -0.267396 + 3.83288 x

```
lm4 = LinearModelFit[Log@Select[MuhData, #[[1]] > 1 &], x, x]
Normal[lm4]
```

> -0.214781 + 2.72766 x

```
Show[Plot[Normal@lm3, {x, -1.5, 0}, PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True], 
 Plot[Normal@lm4, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  Frame -> True], loglogstuff, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Or

```
f3 = Normal[lm3] /. x -> Log[x] // Exp
f4 = Normal[lm4] /. x -> Log[x] // Exp

Show[LogLogPlot[f3, {x, 0.3, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True], 
 LogLogPlot[f4, {x, 1, 2}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  Frame -> True], loglogstuff, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: what about the issue of finding 2 fits, one for small x and one for large x?

Comment: What are "small" and "large"? The division is not very clear from the loglogplot.

Comment: True, I define small as the first two points lets say and large as the last two points

Comment: @Shrodinger2016.  You have no business getting 2 fits with just 6 data points.  (Plus, the linear fit doesn't seem to be too bad.)

Comment: These data points are averages of 10 trials each, and I am expected to have two power law relationships. Don't blame me, blame my class for not giving me more supplies.

Comment: Oh your edits are incredible! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Shrodinger2016.  I'm only trying to give good statistical advice.  Even if the data points are averages of 10 million points each, you still have only 6 observations with respect to estimating a relationship between the independent variable and the dependent variable.  I wish it were otherwise.

Comment: Yeah I see where you are coming from, but I'm just doing what I have to do :(

Comment: @Shrodinger2016 I don't think fitting two (!) small points is a good idea at all.

Comment: @corey979 +1 You probably want your plots with primary axes (see my answer), not their logs...

Answer (score 2):

```
ft = Fit[Log@MuhData, {1, x}, x] /. x -> Log[x] // Exp

Show[ListLogLogPlot[{MuhData}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
  PlotMarkers -> {{\[FilledSquare], 15}}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   PointLegend[Automatic, {"Large"}, LegendFunction -> Frame]], 
 LogLogPlot[ft, {x, 0.3, 2.0}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> Full]]
```

[image]